# My view in mvc returns different value to post action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, input, view

I have an model as you can see here:

```
public partial class AssistanceJuror
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AssistanceId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Assistance Assistance { get; set; }
}
```

I have an action in my controller that returns my `edit` view .

```
   @model DomainClass.AssistanceJuror

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutIdeaOtherPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>View1</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>AssistanceJuror</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssistanceId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssistanceId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssistanceId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My edit action is like this :

```
  public ActionResult EditExpert(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.listAssistance = new SelectList(objAssistanceRepository.ReturnAssitanceWithoutExpert(), "Id",
                                                "AssistanceName");
        AssistanceJuror t = new AssistanceJuror();

        if (objAssistanceJurorRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == id).Count() == 1)
        {
            t = objAssistanceJurorRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == id).First();
        }
        return View(t);
    }
```

My post

```
    [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Expert")]
        public ActionResult EditExpert(AssistanceJuror assistanceJuror)
        {

        }
```

Let explain my problem in `edit` action i return an `AssistanceJuror` to my view with `id=5` ,but as you can see i hold the `AssistanceJuror.id` in `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)` ,but after clicking on submit button the id that is returned by view is changed to `4` .

[image]
Best regards

I change this :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

to this :

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
    </div>
```

And the value that appears in the textbox is `4` i mean the userid.

After executing the edit get maction my html code input values is like this :

```
<form action="/Assistance/EditExpert/4" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>AssistanceJuror</legend>

        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="4" />


        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="UserId">UserId</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field UserId must be a number." data-val-required="The UserId field is required." id="UserId" name="UserId" type="number" value="4" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Date">Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" type="datetime" value="8/28/2014 12:38:01 PM" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Date" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>



        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="AssistanceId">AssistanceId</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AssistanceId must be a number." data-val-required="The AssistanceId field is required." id="AssistanceId" name="AssistanceId" type="number" value="4" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AssistanceId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of getting id this way why don't you get with model.Id in controller action

Comment: could you please explain that in more details ? \

Comment: your first one action is [Httpget] and second action is [HttpPost]..right in above question????

Comment: yes you are right but i don't know how can i pass the value by the model .i need more details if it is possible

Comment: you have assistanceJuror object in your post controller action your id will automatically bind to assistanceJuror object on form submit..just apply breakpoint there and check

Comment: @Exception in the post method i get the id using model am i right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60159/discussion-between-e-a-and-exception).

Comment: That's not possible unless you have some javascript that is changing the value. Your LINQ query is `...FindBy(i => i.UserId == id)`. Are you sure you don't mean `...FindBy(i => i.ID== id)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i changed the view .you know in get method i pass the userid .

Comment: If in the GET method, your passing `UserID=5`, are you saying that in the POST that `UserID=4` or `ID=4`?

Comment: Just let me explian in details.i pass userid=4 to edit ,in my database i have a record that has a userid with userid=4 so the repository returns that value the id of this record is 5 so i pass this record to my view but after clicking on submit button the value is changed i mean the id that was 5 before!!!!is changed to 4,i put a breakpoint in view and the value was 5 there too

Comment: we found something new the view post the userid instead id of the model why !!!!

Comment: You have inputs for `Id`, `Date`, `UserId` and `AssistanceId` so they all post back.  Are you sure your accessing the right property?

Comment: You know the id in view is correct but after post back it is going to be changed ,what you mean ?Are you sure your accessing the right property?

Comment: Based on your Razor code, your html should include `<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="5"..>`, `<input type="text" name="UserId" value="4"..>` and `<input type="text" name="AssistanceId" value="4"..>` (the key points here are the `name` and `value` attributes). Is this what you get?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have updated the post please take a look

Comment: The hidden input for `Id` has a value of `4` (not 5) so its posting back correctly, - its just not posting the value you expect. Are you absolutely sure that when you call `return View(t);` the value of `t.Id` is actually `5` (and not `4`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem .the problem was the name of the parameters :

In get method i get an id as you can see here :

```
public ActionResult EditExpert(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.listAssistance = new SelectList(objAssistanceRepository.ReturnAssitanceWithoutExpert(), "Id",
                                                "AssistanceName");
        AssistanceJuror t = new AssistanceJuror();

        if (objAssistanceJurorRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == id).Count() == 1)
        {
            t = objAssistanceJurorRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == id).First();
        }
        return View(t);
    }
```

So when the id is passed to this action  the mvc tries to match these values to your model and here is the problem the mvc tries to put the id to your model's id but in fact this value that i get is user id after changing the name of the parameter to userid the problem solved :

```
public ActionResult EditExpert(int userid)
{
    ViewBag.listAssistance = new SelectList(objAssistanceRepository.ReturnAssitanceWithoutExpert(), "Id",
                                            "AssistanceName");
    AssistanceJuror t = new AssistanceJuror();

    if (objAssistanceJurorRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == userid).Count() == 1)
    {
        t = objAssistanceJurorRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == userid).First();
    }
    return View(t);
}
```